# How to use ALSA ttable syntax to swap side and rear channels in 5.1 audio?

Tags: alsa

I have 5.1 speakers.

I have noticed that if I select 5.1 configuration and try to test the sound, when the test reaches to rear left and rear right I don't hear anything. I found that if I choose 7.1 configuration when the test reaches to side left and side right I hear sound from rear left and rear right.

Can I use the `ttable` syntax to tell ALSA to create a 5.1 to 7.1 configuration where `front(left/right)`, `center` and `lfe` will be unchanged and `rear(left,right)` will be mapped to `side(left,right)`? Will this be selectable from UI in KDE or GNOME sound configuration applets?

Comment: Yes indeed, everything is possible with Alsa. THE PROBLEM is that I suspect your system to be pulseaudio-ed (I have even been told that it became compulsory for Gnome) and just too many distro default installing it anyway. Whatever you can configure at alsa level is likely to be ignored or refiddled by pulseaudio. Therefore your sole chance is to go with pulseaudio settings. Regarding HDMI, a full step by step help is available thanks to ArchLinuxers ; https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#HDMI_output_configuration : GOOD LUCK !

Comment: Fedora 36 I think uses Pipewire